# if statement doesn't work in Jquery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I used if statements before in a the success function of an ajax call but for the life of me I can't get this to work. I can alert all VARS and they show the data, but the condition statement will not work. What am I doing wrong? I just can't get it.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/uiProcessPhoto.php",
                data: "action="+ action,
                success: function(response){            
                    var s_response = response.split("|");
                    var qsize = data.fileCount;     
                    var ptotal = s_response[0];
                    var ltotal = s_response[1];
                    var allowed = s_response[1] - s_response[0];        
                    if (ptotal >= ltotal){
                    alert("Unable to add photos to queue. You have reached the maximum number of photo uploads allowed.");
                    }else if (ptotal + qsize >= ltotal){                    
                    alert("The total photos select will exceed the maximum upload limit. Please upload up to " + allowed + " more photos to continue.");
                    }else if (response == 1){
                    jQuery('#upload').show();
                    };
                    alert(allowed);
                    }   
                });
```

Comment: Why did you remove your response BalusC? I saw what it was and it worked. I was going to accept it but it gave me an error that it was deleted. ???

Comment: There was a glitch in my mind (it's late right now). To put myself safe, I deleted the answer and I tried to reproduce the problem, just to be sure. I finally realized that I was right, so I brought the answer back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating `ptotal` and `qtotal` as strings, not as numbers. Under each the `+` in the following line

```
}else if (ptotal + qsize >= ltotal){
```

will cause them to be glued together rather than be sum up.

You'd like to parse those strings into real numbers:

```
var ptotal = parseInt(s_response[0]);
var ltotal = parseInt(s_response[1]);
```

Comment: Oh I see why you removed the first answer, You added more clarification. Thanks for the quick answer. It did work.